# jQuery .load() issue in IE, Sinatra

Tags: jquery, ajax, heroku, sinatra

I'm building a site, almost done, but I ran into an issue when testing on IE8. Take a look at:

http://ryanrogalski.com/creepyhtml

When you go to another part of the site via the nav bar, the content in the middle fades out then isn't replaced. I'm assuming this is an issue with .load() as its only on IE, works fine on Chrome, FF, and Safari.

I also have the site built and hosted at http://creepy.heroku.com and it is working fine, but is using Sinatra. The client wants the site as basic html, so I am stuck fixing something that already works fine because they don't want to host on heroku.

Heres my nav.js script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = $('#nav a');
    link.click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        link.removeClass('color');
        $(this).addClass('color');
        $('#container').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).empty().load(href + ' #container',function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = $('#head a');
    link.click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#container').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).empty().load(href + ' #container',function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Anyone have any ideas as to how I could edit this to allow the content to load back in?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: add an error handler to see what is going wrong, however, i'm almost positive it is going to be "parseerror" suggesting that there is a problem with the structure of the returned html. `$.ajaxSetup({error:function(x,y,z){alert(y)});`

Comment: OMG at long last I have finally fixed this by adding doctype and html, head and body tags to the html docs that are being imported. I HATE U IE I H8 U SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't seem to like the object tags or whitespace (carriage returns/line feeds). Can you remove them? =)

```
$.get("creepy_music.html?" + new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
    $('#container').html(data.replace(/[\r\n]*\\|object*/g, ''));
});
```